# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;) exception in sorting arraylist android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList` in Java in Android app but I'm getting this weird exception.

Code:

```
eventsList.sort(new Comparator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event event, Event t1) {
            return event.getEventStartDate().compareTo(t1.getEventStartDate());
        }
    });
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`ArrayList#sort()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) was added in API level 24 and runtimes below API level 24 don't have that method. Looks like your `compileSdkVersion` is at 24 so you got the code to compile in the first place.

Use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` instead.

Comment: mmmm, I used to use `Collection.sort` long back ago but today I just found this method in code completion in Android studio but likely it was a trap :). Thanks

Answer (score 30):

**Zxing?**

If you get this error in the Zxing core lib in `com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder.selectBestPatterns` you can solve it by downgrading Zxing to 3.3.x (3.3.3 currently).

See https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/1170 for details.

Answer (score 15):

In **Zxing** no need to downgrade version

just add following in **App level gradle**

```
android{
....
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    ......
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

Comment: I found [this same answer elsewhere](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/1170#issuecomment-555860273) but THIS is the right thing to do in 2021 so I upvoted.

Comment: this solution worked for me too as I didn't want to downgrade

Answer (score 6):

What if you try

```
Collections.sort(eventsList, new Comparator...
```

As far as I know `ArrayList` doesn't have `sort` method.

Answer (score 4):

List doesn't have its own sorting method, you'll need to call

```
Collections.sort()
```

as the method on the list. If this returns a ClassCastError, that means the list has non-sortable items. I think this should fix it, but without full code, it's hard to check.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList.sort() method was added later that's why its not working. We can update java version (1.8) or we can use below method.

```
Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event event, Event t1) {
            return event.getEventStartDate().compareTo(t1.getEventStartDate());
        }
});
```