# Espresso Test Failing: No interface method trackUsage() in UsageTracker.java

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I'm receiving a runtime error *No interface method trackUsage() in UsageTracker.java* when the lines run in the Espresso test to scroll to a certain element in the RecyclerView list:

```
   onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(scrollTo(hasDescendant(withText(text))));
```

I'm using *RecyclerViewActions* for the **scrollTo()** method.

Here are my current configurations and gradle dependencies:

- Android Studio 3.0 Canery 9
- compileSdkVersion 25
- buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
- junit:junit:4.12
- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0
- com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.0
- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2
- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
- Android Support Library: 25.3.1

Also, for each of the **androidTestCompile**'s I'm using the following excludes:

- exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
- exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
- exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
- exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'

**Full error message:** No interface method trackUsage(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/support/test/internal/runner/tracker/UsageTracker; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.test.internal.runner.tracker.UsageTracker' appears in /data/app/adamhurwitz.github.io.doordashlite.test-2/base.apk)

Comment: Check for the version of UsageTracker. Here you have a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951218/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-interface-method-sortljava-util-comparator-ex/38951385#38951385

Comment: Is UsageTracker declaring the trackUsage in its interface?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ivan The *trackUsage()* method is defined in the UsageTracker interface.

Comment: My current hypothesis is this is an issue with *Android Studio 3.0 Canery 9*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue with *rules 1.0.0* and *runner 1.0.0*. Though I was able to solve it by just adding *espresso-core 3.0.0*. Which avoids the use of outdated versions such as suggested in Erics answer.

```
com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.0 
com.android.support.test.runner:1.0.0 
com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0
```

**EDIT:**
Meanwhile one should use the *AndroidX* libraries, the current versions as of 2021 / 12 are:

```
androidx.test:rules:1.4.0
androidx.test:runner:1.4.0
androidx.test:core:1.4.0
androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0
```

The up to date versions can in general be found on the [Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#android-test-dependencies).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. To fix it I changed the following dependencies from:

```
com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0
com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.0
```

to:

```
com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
```

**UPDATE:**

Michael's answer is better, don't use this outdated version anymore!